# My scraper yields too many items instead of merging them all into only a small bunch

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I've written a scraper that should go through several pages for each soccer team and basically get all historical data, eventually merging each one into a pretty json file with 1 item for each team.

So e.g. I end up with something for each team like so:

```
{'clubName': [u'West Ham United'],
 'matches': [{'date': [u'17/08/1974'],
          'opponent': [u'Manchester City'],
          'place': [u'A'],
          'results': [u'0:4 '],
          'round': [u'1. Round'],
          'time': []},
         {'date': [u'19/08/1974'],
          'opponent': [u'Luton Town'],
          'place': [u'H'],
          'results': [u'2:0 '],
          'round': [u'2. Round'],
          'time': []},
         {'date': [u'24/08/1974'],
          'opponent': [u'Everton FC'],
          'place': [u'H'],
          'results': [u'2:3 '],
          'round': [u'3. Round'],
          'time': []},
```

Basically the functions are:

1. Get the 20 teams, and then links to their pages
2. Get the link for historic results
3. Get all the links for the seasons from the historic results
4. Merge the match data back into the item

To debug, I've yielded the item after each function. I should end up with 20 items. If I yield item after 1,2 & 3 functions, I end up with just 20 rows, which is perfect, but it is in the 4th function where it gets chaotic and I end up with thousands of items. Many multiple items per club etc.

I'm ending up with items like this:

```
{"matches": [], "clubName": ["Arsenal FC"]},
{"matches": [], "clubName": ["Arsenal FC"]},
{"matches": [], "clubName": ["Arsenal FC"]},
{"matches": [], "clubName": ["Arsenal FC"]},
{"matches": [], "clubName": ["Arsenal FC"]},
{"matches": [], "clubName": ["Arsenal FC"]},
{"matches": [], "clubName": ["Arsenal FC"]},
{"matches": [], "clubName": ["Arsenal FC"]},
{"matches": [], "clubName": ["Arsenal FC"]},
```

Sometimes 30 in a row of basically blank items except for the club name.

I'm new to python, and I've been looking at this thing all morning not being able to work out why this isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

from ..items import PremierleagueItem

class PremierleagueSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "premierleague"
    allowed_domains = ["worldfootball.net"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.worldfootball.net/competition/eng-premier-league/"
    ]


# get teams in the match
def parse(self, response):

    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="tabelle_0"]/div[@class="data"]/table[1]/tr'):       

        clubName = sel.xpath('.//td[3]/a/text()').extract()

        if clubName:

            item = PremierleagueItem()

            item['clubName'] = clubName

            clubHref = sel.xpath('.//td[2]/a/@href').extract_first()
            clubUrl = response.urljoin(clubHref)

            request = scrapy.Request(clubUrl,callback=self.parse_get_historic_results_link)

            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request


def parse_get_historic_results_link(self,response):

    item = response.meta['item']

    href2 = response.xpath('//div[@class="navibox2"]/div[@class="data"]/ul[5]/li[2]/a[1]/@href').extract_first()
    url2 = response.urljoin(href2)

    request = scrapy.Request(url2,callback=self.parse_seasons)

    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request

def parse_seasons(self,response):

    item = response.meta['item']

    for sel in response.xpath('(//table[@class="standard_tabelle"])[1]/tr/td[2]/a'):

        href = sel.xpath('.//@href').extract_first()
        url = response.urljoin(href)

        request = scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_results)
        request.meta['item'] = item

        yield request


def parse_results(self,response):

    item = response.meta['item']

    item['matches'] = []

    for sel in response.xpath('(//table[@class="standard_tabelle"])[1]/tr'):

        results = sel.xpath('.//td[7]/a/text()').extract()

        if results:

            matchDict = {
                'round' : sel.xpath('.//td[1]/a/text()').extract(),
                'date' : sel.xpath('.//td[2]/a/text()').extract(),
                'time'  : sel.xpath('.//td[3]/text()').extract(),
                'place' : sel.xpath('.//td[4]/text()').extract(),
                'opponent' : sel.xpath('.//td[6]/a/text()').extract(),
                'results' : results
            }

            item['matches'].append(matchDict)

   yield item
```

What have I stuffed up here?

**Edit**

Just to clarify, the  ideal format we would end up with is a multi dimensional array, such as (pseudo code):

```
Team name Y {
        premierLeagueMatches { 
            {'date': [...],
            'opponent': [...],
            'place': [...],
            'results': [...],
            'round': [...],
            'time': [...]
            }
        otherMatches {
          same as above
        }
},
Team name X {
        premierLeagueMatches { 
            {'date': [...],
            'opponent': [...],
            'place': [...],
            'results': [...],
            'round': [...],
            'time': [...]
            }
        otherMatches {
            same as above
        }
}
```

At the top level of the array, there are only club names and each is unique. There is no duplicate of Team name x or y etc. But currently The only unique key at the top level is the season date.

In the final output of the json with our buggy code, I can do a search for "clubName": [ "West Ham United" ] and get 75 results instead of 1. So although there is tonnes of data going back to circa 1900s :) Instead of the scrape count currently being 1670 (which i'm guessing is the total number of seasons * the number of teams in the premier league), I'm trying to end up with just 20 items (one for each team).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpaths were wrong in parse_results, this is a runnable example getting the data you want:

```
import scrapy


class PremierleagueItem(scrapy.Item):
    round = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()
    time = scrapy.Field()
    place = scrapy.Field()
    opponent = scrapy.Field()
    results = scrapy.Field()
    clubName = scrapy.Field()
    matches = scrapy.Field()


class PremierleagueSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "premierleague"
    allowed_domains = ["worldfootball.net"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.worldfootball.net/competition/eng-premier-league/"
    ]

    # get teams in the match
    def parse(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="tabelle_0"]/div[@class="data"]/table[1]/tr'):

            clubName = sel.xpath('.//td[3]/a/text()').extract()

            if clubName:
                item = PremierleagueItem()

                item['clubName'] = clubName

                clubHref = sel.xpath('.//td[2]/a/@href').extract_first()
                clubUrl = response.urljoin(clubHref)

                request = scrapy.Request(clubUrl, callback=self.parse_get_historic_results_link)

                request.meta['item'] = item
                yield request

    def parse_get_historic_results_link(self, response):

        item = response.meta['item']

        href2 = response.xpath('//div[@class="navibox2"]/div[@class="data"]/ul[5]/li[2]/a[1]/@href').extract_first()
        url2 = response.urljoin(href2)

        request = scrapy.Request(url2, callback=self.parse_seasons)

        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

    def parse_seasons(self, response):

        item = response.meta['item']

        for sel in response.xpath('(//table[@class="standard_tabelle"])[1]/tr/td[2]/a'):
            href = sel.xpath('.//@href').extract_first()
            url = response.urljoin(href)

            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_results)
            request.meta['item'] = item

            yield request

    @staticmethod
    def parse_results(response):

        item = response.meta['item']

        item['matches'] = []
        for sel in response.xpath('(//table[@class="standard_tabelle"])[1]/tr[position() > 3]'):
                matchDict = dict(zip((
                    'round',
                    'date',
                    'place',
                         'opponent',
                'results'), filter(None, map(unicode.strip,(sel.xpath("./td[normalize-space(.)]//text()").extract())))))
                item['matches'].append(matchDict)
        yield item
```

A snippet of the output:

```
{'clubName': [u'Manchester City'],
 'matches': [{'date': u'09/09/1911',
              'opponent': u'Liverpool FC',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'2:2',
              'round': u'2. Round'},
             {'date': u'16/09/1911',
              'opponent': u'Aston Villa',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'2:6',
              'round': u'3. Round'},
             {'date': u'23/09/1911',
              'opponent': u'Newcastle United',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'0:1',
              'round': u'4. Round'},
             {'date': u'30/09/1911',
              'opponent': u'Sheffield United',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'0:0',
              'round': u'5. Round'},
             {'date': u'07/10/1911',
              'opponent': u'Oldham Athletic',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'1:4',
              'round': u'6. Round'},
             {'date': u'14/10/1911',
              'opponent': u'Bolton Wanderers',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'3:1',
              'round': u'8. Round'},
             {'date': u'21/10/1911',
              'opponent': u'Bradford City',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'1:4',
              'round': u'9. Round'},
             {'date': u'28/10/1911',
              'opponent': u'Woolwich Arsenal',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'3:3',
              'round': u'9. Round'},
             {'date': u'04/11/1911',
              'opponent': u'Preston North End',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'1:2',
              'round': u'10. Round'},
             {'date': u'11/11/1911',
              'opponent': u'Everton FC',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'0:1',
              'round': u'12. Round'},
             {'date': u'18/11/1911',
              'opponent': u'West Bromwich Albion',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'0:2',
              'round': u'12. Round'},
             {'date': u'25/11/1911',
              'opponent': u'Sunderland AFC',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'1:1',
              'round': u'13. Round'},
             {'date': u'02/12/1911',
              'opponent': u'Blackburn Rovers',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'3:0',
              'round': u'15. Round'},
             {'date': u'09/12/1911',
              'opponent': u'Sheffield Wednesday',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'0:3',
              'round': u'15. Round'},
             {'date': u'16/12/1911',
              'opponent': u'Bury FC',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'2:0',
              'round': u'16. Round'},
             {'date': u'23/12/1911',
              'opponent': u'Middlesbrough FC',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'1:3',
              'round': u'17. Round'},
             {'date': u'25/12/1911',
              'opponent': u'Notts County',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'1:0',
              'round': u'18. Round'},
             {'date': u'26/12/1911',
              'opponent': u'Notts County',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'4:0',
              'round': u'19. Round'},
             {'date': u'30/12/1911',
              'opponent': u'Manchester United',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'0:0',
              'round': u'20. Round'},
             {'date': u'06/01/1912',
              'opponent': u'Liverpool FC',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'2:3',
              'round': u'21. Round'},
             {'date': u'20/01/1912',
              'opponent': u'Aston Villa',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'1:3',
              'round': u'22. Round'},
             {'date': u'27/01/1912',
              'opponent': u'Newcastle United',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'1:1',
              'round': u'23. Round'},
             {'date': u'10/02/1912',
              'opponent': u'Oldham Athletic',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'1:3',
              'round': u'24. Round'},
             {'date': u'17/02/1912',
              'opponent': u'Bolton Wanderers',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'1:2',
              'round': u'27. Round'},
             {'date': u'26/02/1912',
              'opponent': u'Sheffield United',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'2:6',
              'round': u'26. Round'},
             {'date': u'02/03/1912',
              'opponent': u'Woolwich Arsenal',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'0:2',
              'round': u'28. Round'},
             {'date': u'09/03/1912',
              'opponent': u'Preston North End',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'0:0',
              'round': u'28. Round'},
             {'date': u'16/03/1912',
              'opponent': u'Everton FC',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'4:0',
              'round': u'29. Round'},
             {'date': u'23/03/1912',
              'opponent': u'West Bromwich Albion',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'1:1',
              'round': u'30. Round'},
             {'date': u'28/03/1912',
              'opponent': u'Bradford City',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'4:0',
              'round': u'31. Round'},
             {'date': u'30/03/1912',
              'opponent': u'Sunderland AFC',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'2:0',
              'round': u'32. Round'},
             {'date': u'05/04/1912',
              'opponent': u'Tottenham Hotspur',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'2:1',
              'round': u'33. Round'},
             {'date': u'06/04/1912',
              'opponent': u'Blackburn Rovers',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'0:2',
              'round': u'31. Round'},
             {'date': u'08/04/1912',
              'opponent': u'Tottenham Hotspur',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'2:0',
              'round': u'35. Round'},
             {'date': u'13/04/1912',
              'opponent': u'Sheffield Wednesday',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'4:0',
              'round': u'36. Round'},
             {'date': u'20/04/1912',
              'opponent': u'Bury FC',
              'place': u'A',
              'results': u'2:1',
              'round': u'37. Round'},
             {'date': u'27/04/1912',
              'opponent': u'Middlesbrough FC',
              'place': u'H',
              'results': u'2:0',
              'round': u'38. Round'}]}
```

You will need to do a bit more to get the exact format you want but whatever you do you need to use the correct xpaths, you should also be aware that you are going back to circa 1900 so there is going to be a lot of output that may be better suited to a db. I also pulled just the first table from each page which when there is more than one is the league results, there are pages with just F.A cups results etc  and yput teams etc... If you wanted to get all the data it would be something like:

```
for tbl in response.xpath('(//table[@class="standard_tabelle"])'):
            for sel in tbl.xpath("./tr[position() > 3]"):
                matchDict = dict(zip((
                    'round',
                    'date',
                    'place',
                    'opponent',
                    'results'),
                    filter(None, map(unicode.strip, (sel.xpath("./td[normalize-space(.)]//text()").extract())))))
                item['matches'].append(matchDict)
        yield item
```

There are also some cup results in the lower part of the first tables so if you just want premier league:

```
@staticmethod
def parse_results(response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['matches'] = []
    table = response.xpath('(//table[@class="standard_tabelle"])[1]')
    for sel in table.xpath("./tr[position() > 3]"):
        title = sel.xpath("./td/a/@title").extract_first()
        if title and "premier" not in title.lower():
            return
        matchDict = dict(zip((
            'round',
            'date',
            'place',
            'opponent',
            'results'),
            filter(None, map(unicode.strip, (sel.xpath("./td[normalize-space(.)]//text()").extract())))))
        item['matches'].append(matchDict)
    yield item
```

Comment: I'm just studying and studying this answer. So many new things in there I have not seen before. I was also wondering how to filter results like other leagues. I just ran your version of the code though, and I'm still getting more than 20 items. e.g. If I search for "clubName": ["Arsenal FC"], there should only be one search match. i.e. your code does a similar thing where it creates a new item for every season year. See http://imgur.com/fx0a8lW ?

Comment: All those Stoke City matches should all be together in the same array.

Comment: The best I can explain it is that instead of the 'yield item' happening in parse_results, it should actually happen after it has finished parse_seasons. But for it to finish parse_seasons, it has to first finish parse_results. Is there a way to only yield after both parse_seasons and parse_results have both completed their loops per team?

Comment: i will throw together a full working example in a bit, what do you want to scrape, just the league and all the years from ~1900+? Lastly exactly what kind of format do you want?

Comment: Thanks Padraic, I just updated with an edit to hopefully clarify a little

Comment: @willdanceforfun, so you want one array per team housing all premier/ league matches since ~1900? Also would you maybe think a db would be more suitable? Even a simple sqlite3?

Comment: Why you seem multiple entries is because the data is not scraped in a particular order, it is done for different years so the order is arbitrary, really a db would be the ideal solution running the items through a pipeline

Comment: I think I see what you mean. But even though it scrapes in no particular order, why doesn't when I go yield item, in the last function, doesn't it put it all into the one item? Because the way I see it, parse_results is a loop inside parse_seasons. I thought maybe it would be possible to put yield item in the parse_seasons function instead somehow, getting the results from parse_results and returning them back to parse_seasons. That sort of logic.

Comment: You are creating a new Item each iteration, that gets updated and yielded so for each scrape/page so there is no relationship between the Items, this is why you need a database or something that can group all the common elements. Do you just want the premier results?

Comment: I see now. Getting the db going now. Thank you very much for all the ideas you gave. Definitely solved more than one problem! Cheers

Comment: No worries,  I update the method do it should only get premier league matches

Comment: It's quite brilliant. Thank you, again. Just 1 queries I have :D What does putting the @staticmethod there do?